# AngularJS: apply class to multiple elements in array on click

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I'm teaching myself angular and working through the O'Reilly AngularJS book.  There's an email app example and I want to add a button "Mark as Read" that will apply a class to the row when the button is clicked.

After doing some research I found solutions applying conditional classes based on using $index to select a row, but that is toggling the class from the other elements when I click the button.   You can see what I'm talking about here [in this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ag7XQtAdGffcLxmiPxHm?p=preview).

Here's the HTML in my view:

```
    <table>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Sender</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Subject</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Date</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat='message in messages' ng-click='readMessage($index)'
          ng-class='{markRead: $index==selectedRow}'>
    <td>{{message.sender}}</td>
    <td><a ng-href='#/view/{{message.id}}'>{{message.subject}}</a></td>
    <td>{{message.date}}</td>
    <td><button  ng-click="remove(message)">Delete</button></td>
    <td><button  ng-click="markRead()">Mark as Read</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and here is what I have added to the controller to apply the class on click:

```
  $scope.readMessage = function(row) {
    $scope.selectedRow = row;
  };
```

My goal is to have the ability to apply the class to any and all elements in the array, as the user desires (not just one at a time).

Can someone please help me understand why this isn't working and how I can achieve my goal?  All the questions/answers I can find on SO are about toggling classes or setting an active class, which is the opposite of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `readMessage` could flag the message as `read`, and `ng-class` set the css class if the flag is set:

**Controller:**

```
$scope.readMessage = function(message) {
    message.read = true;
};
```

**Template:**

```
ng-class='{markRead: message.read}'
```

See **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0A2lBdJKdmgDHP8Gw9KH?p=preview)**